# How to display default value from prompt macro in value prompt CA11?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I was wondering if it is possible to display the default value from a prompt macro in a Value prompt. My prompt macro looks like this "#prompt('pMonth','MUN','[Previous Month]')#"
so my goal in the value prompt would be to have 202103 displayed instead of header text name which I have named "Previous Month"

[image]

I tried with an old javascript from Cognos 10 where you desc the Months and specify what index it should pick but the issue with that code is that everytime you try to change to a different month the report re-runs and loops back to to the same Index value.

```
<script>
var theSpan = document.getElementById("A1");
var a = theSpan.getElementsByTagName("select");   /* This stmt return an array of all value prompts within span */
for( var i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i-- )  /* now loop through the elements */
{   var prompts = a[i];
if( prompts.id.match(/PRMT_SV_/))
 {  prompts.selectedIndex = 2;  } /* This selects the second options from top */
canSubmitPrompt();
}
</script>
```

All solutions, tips and ideas are highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Rubrix

Comment: Turn off Auto-submit.

Comment: But then you would need to have a ugly button @dougp

Comment: But you're complaint is that when you select a value, the report runs.

Comment: Well not really. The Issue was to find a solution that can display default value. The javascript was just a potential solution that I tried but did not fully  meet the requirements. Preferably using Custom control so that interactivity can be set to ”yes”. I should probably edit the post and clearify that.

Comment: Relational or dimensional data?

Comment: Dimensional data SSAS OLAP Cube

Comment: And no prompt page.  The prompt is on the report page?

Comment: Exactly, only two optional value prompts on the report page. Both of them are prompt macros in the slicer filter.

Answer (score 0):

For Cognos Analytics, running with full interactivity, you probably need a Page Module.  Check out [IBM's Scriptable Reports documentation for Cognos Analytics](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/sw-library/cognos/mobile/scriptable_reports/index.html).  You'll want to craft your script to use the current parameter value as default (if you can get it), then fail over to your default value from the data.  You will probably need to integrate this with a Custom Control to be able to get that default value from the data.